# How to differentiate between redirect url and single url in android webView?

Tags: android, url, webview

I have a webView inside the activity and the body of that webView has some links (assume around 5 links one below the other).

My requirement is when I tap on the link I am checking weather the url string contains with particular string(for example  : "xyz") in shouldOverrideUrlLoading method. if the URL contains "xyz" I will launch the url in webView itself, otherwise I am launching url in browser.

Now the problem is if the link doesn't contains the "xyz" and the url is redirected to another URL on tapping and if the redirected URL contains "xyz" I need to open the url in webView. So how to handle this situation.

Please suggest me on this to fix the issue.

Comment: What if you first get the redirection URL and then decide the web client(either your app OR the native browser application)?

Comment: But the thing is I am not sure the link will redirect. There might be a chance of that link doesn't have the redirect url.

Comment: You may use ***HttpURLConnection*** API to check the redirection by looking at the status code [**200** (OK,NO Rediection) , **301/302** (Rediection)] and catch the redirected URL.

Comment: I have to decide as soon as I clicked a link in side webView body. When I  tap on that shouldOverideUrlLoading will get called.